# Adding columns to an existing django table with a . postgreSQL db

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, django-migrations

I've been searching around for how to do this an di think i broke my table

I tried adding

```
dealership = models.ForeignKey('Employee', null=True)
```

To the field to the models.py, since I noticed thats where my other column fields were, and now the entire table is gone.

After some more research I saw that its supposed to be added to the migrations location and then run

```
$ python models.py migrations
```

Heres the model I want to add it to

```
## Gate access log - receives from RPi via API
##
class Eventlog(models.Model):
    ENTRY = 1
    EXIT = 2
    EVENT_CHOICES = (
        (ENTRY, 'Entry'),
        (EXIT, 'Exit'),
    )
    event = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=EVENT_CHOICES)
    employee = models.ForeignKey('Employee', null=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    status = models.BooleanField(default=True, help_text="Whether the employee was granted access")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.timestamp

    def __str__(self):
        return self.timestamp
```

and as the comment suggests, it pulls the from a raspberry pi through an api

My question is how do I properly add the column, the db already has the information for the column data I can't imagine it's that difficult to simply pull that info and how do I get my table back? The table seems to have vanished after I added to the models.py manually and when I tried undoing it just never came back.

Comment: Does the table already have the dealership column and you want to add it on the model? Or is it a new column in an existing model?

Comment: Yes the column is already added and has its placement holder. I want to add it to an existing model called eventlog

Answer (score 1):

You need to run two commands:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

then

```
python manage.py migrate
```

Comment: is this with the added field i want in the migrations file or the models one?

Comment: the whole project

Comment: sorry if im being slow, just trying to make sure i get a full and complete understanding, whole project? meaning? both models and migrations? its already in my page template and in the postgresSQL DB as a cloumn

Comment: you need to go to the command line, and run `makemigrations` to create the migrations file. then ask Django to execute it with `migrate`. thats how you add, delete or modify models in Django

Comment: i got a traceback saying that module widget-tweaks was not found, i checked the settings  i found this in my settings.py `INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'core',
    'api',
    'widget_tweaks',
]`

but it looks like the widget-tweaks lives inside 

`/ve/lib/python3.5/site-packages/widget_tweaks/`

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: use `pip install django-widget-tweaks` before running the commands

Answer (score 0):

To add columns in postgresql db solution as below:

```
pip install django-extensions
```

and add this in the install app of settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django_extensions'
]
```

Now, run migrations for your installed apps

```
python manage.py makemigrations your_app_name
python manage.py migrtate your_app_name
```

Done! See Your Database...